# Sharing an ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, ethernet

My dorm room provides an ethernet connection. Since I wanted to share it and create a wireless connection, I connected the ethernet connection to the router to create a wireless connection.

The problem is that I should login through a proxy connection which my university provides, and there can be only one login per IP. The router is assigned a IP by the university. When I connect two or more devices, there are assigned local IP addresses. But there can be only one login as there is only one IP assigned to the router by the university.

What should I do the share the ethernet connection?

Comment: Have you spoken with the campus IT about this yet? Sounds like maybe your university doesn't want you sharing your connection.

Comment: @techie007      We are allowed to connect routers

Comment: which os are you using ?

Comment: @DEFCON1       Backtrack linux

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Windows  desktop around, you could try using ICS, and logging on to the proxy via the desktop when needed:

- Obtain a desktop computer if you don't already have one.
- Put 2 NICs in this desktop.
- Connect ethernet cable from wall to one NIC.
- Login to your proxy using the desktop.  You can also use this desktop for normal use.
- Connect an ethernet cable from the 2nd NIC in your desktop to a LAN port on a wireless router.
- Typically the default login of a wireless router is 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.254.  Find this information out for sure though.
- Set your second NIC to something like 192.168.1.55, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and no default gateway or DNS.  You should then be able to log in to the wireless router's configuration interface.
- Set the wireless router's IP to 192.168.1.200.  Disable DHCP.  If you can't disable DHCP, flash it to DD-WRT or find another one that will let you.  You can also configure the SSID, wireless password and such as well.
- Enable Internet Connection Sharing on the second NIC.  You may need to remove the static IP assignment 192.168.1.55 earlier.
- Login to your school's proxy when necessary on the desktop.  Anyone connecting to the wireless router should be getting Internet via the ICS.  ICS has a built-in DHCP server and handles NAT as well.

You can use a laptop as well, if you get a USB to Ethernet adapter.  The only thing is that you might want to take the laptop with you so then  those connected could no longer use the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

create a Virtual Wifi Access Point.

In linux , you can use hostapd to setup a virtual wifi access point given your wireless card supports master mode.check this  [link](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/) to know more about creating Virtual Wifi Access Point